# Function not declared in the scope (C++)

Tags: c++, function, scope

I've been working on this Morris-Pratt algorithm to match substrings to a text, and I'm having trouble how to declare the failure function in the actual function so the compiler won't complain. I have like 2 hours to finish this. So please help me soon :/

```
int KMPmatch(const string& text, const string& pattern)
{
  int n = text.size();
  int m = pattern.size();
  std::vector<int> fail = computeFailFunction(pattern);
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;

  while (i < n)
  {
    if (pattern[j] == text[i])
    {
      if (j == m-1) return i-m+1;
      i++; j++;
    }
    else if (j > 0) j = fail[j-1];
    else i++;
  }

  return -1;
}

//KMPFailure function
std::vector<int> computeFailFunction(const string& pattern)
{
  std::vector <int> fail(pattern.size());
  fail[0] = 0;
  int m = pattern.size();
  int j = 0;
  int i = 1;

  while (i < m)
  {
    if (pattern[j] == pattern[i])
    {
      fail[i] = j+1;
      i++; j++;
    }
    else if (j > 0)
    {
      j = fail [j-1];
    }
    else
    {
      fail[i]= 0;
      i++;
    }
  }

  return fail;
}
```

Comment: Did you forward declare `std::vector<int> computeFailFunction(const string& pattern);` before `KMPmatch`?

Comment: No. My bad. Now it compiles perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `std::vector<int> computeFailFunction(const string& pattern);` ahead of  `int KMPmatch(const string& text, const string& pattern)`.

Or put function declaration into header file and included in source files, that is what project with multiple source files do.